# Setting value of properties programatically in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an app where I have a feature that is enabled or disabled via a setting in application.properties like

```
app.thingEnabled=true
```

And of course, it may be true or false. And I have in my controller:

```
@Value("${app.thingEnabled:true}")
private boolean thingEnabled;
```

Of course we check if this is true or false and then either do or don't do the thing.

Now, I want to make this have a feedback mechanism... Like, the Thing Feature writes to a database. If the DB code catches a timeout exception, set thingEnabled to false for 5 mins and then try again. That sort of thing.

Is this possible in Spring? I have thought about creating a separate component as, say, a "ThingConfiguration" which could have properties set on it and then wire the property into that and have the controller just call out to it. Then it could have a getter and setter which could update dynamically but it seems like there might be a better way.

I am also not entirely sure at what point those classes get instantiated and whether they are common across multiple request servicing threads.

Secondly, is there a way to kick off a thread that sleeps those 5 mins and then does some work without having to dig into the low level threading api? I see there's a @Scheduled thing but that looks like it's meant to run some work over and over, not as something initiated by the code itself.

Comment: What's your ultimate goal?  Is this boolean controlling something that can be readily injected, or is it controlling business logic?  That is, is this controlling whether or not you use a specific, injectable component, or is it controlling if you go down one logic path over another?

Comment: It controls if the code follows one path or another.

Comment: What does prevent you to make a setter for it (I guess you already have it) ? then change its value back and forth based on DB timeout or anything else?

Comment: Then the question is how to get a handle on this component from elsewhere in the code and if you like @Autowired ThingController is that the same instance for all threads of execution? Or would it only alter the property on the one in the same thread?

Comment: So far I know... simple @Autowired points to one singleton instance for all threads. Singleton mode is default for Spring beans.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you probably want to separate out is the *eligibility* of your queries from running from their *activation*.  `thingEnabled` determines if your process is activated.  Something *else* should determine if it's *eligible* to run.

Ultimately it depends on how you're writing your queries, but there's nothing native to Spring that would sleep for X minutes and then refire your query.  However, if you split up the logic to determine eligibility, then writing something to check to see if the time deltas meet your criterion become somewhat straightforward.  (I leave this as an exercise for the reader).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title:

> Setting value of properties programatically in SpringBoot

Spring will look for `@Value` annotations only at the start of the application, it will not update by itself after the first instantiation. For instance:

```
@Value("${app.thingEnabled:true}")
private boolean thingEnabled;
```

This will set `thingEnabled` to the value you set in `application.properties`, or to `true` if that property is not found.

Afterward, if you set `thingEnabled` to false, it will stay false. Basically, Spring will only assign the value of `thingEnabled` on start and no more change will be made unless you do them yourself.

In your case,

> Now, I want to make this have a feedback mechanism... Like, the Thing
>   Feature writes to a database. If the DB code catches a timeout
>   exception, set thingEnabled to false for 5 mins and then try again.

Would roughly translate to that:

```
// database operation...
} catch (SQLTimeoutException e) {
    thingEnabled = false; 
    // start a timerTask that will run in 5 minute, and then execute your code again
}
```

But `thingEnabled` is not really relevant in this case and I don't understand what you mean by `feedback` here.

I'll make an assumption that you meant fallback instead.

In that case, you would do the following:

```
// database operation...
} catch (SQLTimeoutException e) {
    if (thingEnabled) { // if the fallback is enabled
        // start a timerTask that will run in 5 minute, and then execute your code again
    }
}
```

That way, setting `app.thingEnabled` would actually be relevant:

- if `app.thingEnabled` is `true`, retry 5 minutes after timeout exception
- if `app.thingEnabled` is `false`, do not retry.

You might want to read up on [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html). Also, a good example can be found [here](http://www.iitk.ac.in/esc101/05Aug/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html).

Comment: TimerTask doesn't play well with Spring... Each Task needs to be instantiated individually so you can't then autowire spring managed components into the TimerTask.

Comment: @MichaelB As long as the TimerTask object is within a component, it can be accessed through autowiring the component itself and accessing the TimerTask through it. Ultimately, you could use `ScheduledExecutorService` but that's still not managed by Spring.

Comment: Example: ConfigReset cr is an autowired in extension of TimerTask. Then `Timer timer = new Timer(); timer.schedule(cr, Date.from(Instant.now().plusSeconds(10)));`. It works once, and then you get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task already scheduled or cancelled` because you need a new instance of the TimerTask class